# How can I fix this problem with drop down menus?

Tags: menu, text

Is this a problem that would have to be fixed with a clean install? I'd rather not do that, if anyone can help me fix this, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? Looks like a theme error, the box should be black with white text but is white with white text. Try another theme to test.

Comment: I tried setting the Desktop Theme, Window Decorations, and Widget Style all to default. The problem is still there. I even switched between Breeze and Breeze Dark a few times, in Breeze the text was black but still in the wrong spot like above.

Answer (score 1):

I updated plasma to 5.8.5, seems to fix the problem.